# Atomic Database Transactions in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, transactions

I want to have atomic transactions on all the requests in the Django app.
There is the following decorator to add an atomic transaction for one request,

```
@transaction.atomic
def create_user(request):
 ....
```

but then, in this case, I'll have to use this decorator for all the APIs.

I tried doing this in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'blah',
            'USER': 'postgres',
            'PASSWORD': 'blah',
            'HOST': '0.0.0.0',
            'PORT': '5432',
            'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True
}
```

But adding ATOMIC_REQUESTS does not seem to work in some cases.
Is there any way so that I can apply atomic transactions for all APIs?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if this the case but in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/transactions/), explains that you need to pass 'using' param to this decorator which is what database this operation applies to.
so
can you try this

```
DATABASES = {
     'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'blah',
            'USER': 'postgres',
            'PASSWORD': 'blah',
            'HOST': '0.0.0.0',
            'PORT': '5432',
            'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
     },
}
```

then like this:

```
@transaction.atomic(using='default')
def create_user(request):
```

I also realized that you used psycopg2 as your engine
Changed in Django 1.9:

from the docs:

> The django.db.backends.postgresql backend is named
> django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2 in older releases. For
> backwards compatibility, the old name still works in newer versions.

fyi